Specific UV maps for each instance in For Each Element
I have created the goemetry node setup that creates a grid with dimensions that are based on the size of instance and the between-instance space. Then using a For Each Element node I am assigning a uv map on two selected faces of each instance. My problem is that each instance should have its specific offset in terms of uv map coordinates because the entire idea is to assign only portion of material to each instance so all of them are making entire image.
My setup calculates also the offset (now only for X axis but the Y axis is the same story) for each individual instance but I do not know how to add that element to calculation of the uv map coordinates.
So lets start from beginning. Below is the top level setup that creates grid, instance mesh on pointsm calculates proper offset for each instance and then creates uv maps for each instance. However the uv map fora each instance is the same.



As you can see on the picture below the vm map is assigned to each instance but it is the same uv map. The tile that is displayed depends on the value of X Position and Y Position.

As I written above I am able to calculate proper offset of each of instance (for debuging purposes it is stored as variable TEST).

All the calculations of uv map coordinate take place in group node called UV Map to Face and the setup of that node is shown below.

I should somehow inject values specific to each individual instance somewhere between Vector Rotate node and Store Named Attribute node but I do not now how. I tried to use TEST attribute (that is stored outside this group) but it did not work. I have modified the setup that calculates the uv map coordinates in the way shown below

But it did not work and the effect of change in terms of final result is lite this

SO the question is how to ensure that calculation of vm map is using values specific for each instance.

Ideally, you keep instancing and store UV offset as additional attribute used in the shader:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror

Imgur mirror
If you really need to modify the UV map of the instances, bad news: UV maps are mesh data, and instances share mesh data (that's the whole idea behind instancing, reusing data), so you can't do it. Now, you can realize instances, making it a single big mesh, recalculate UV map the way I do above in the shader, but do it in geonodes, and then you can split this mesh into instances. The important thing here is: you would throw out the window the advantage of instances, because now each instance points to unique data, so instances, instead of reusing data, are just adding an additional overhead. It's like having 9 cars all compliant with 1 standard, but then you want each car to have a different color, but the standard doesn't allow this, so you create 9 separate standards, each for one car. Of course it would still make sense if you e.g. wanted to duplicate these 9-color cars into 10 groups (totaling 90 cars), then each standard would be used 10 times...

(1/2) Markus. I have a bit of programming experience so I figured out the idea to have a single object (something like class) that stores some common data (like shape, size, beveling and so on and so forth) but then when the object (class in programming) is instantiated some attributes if the instance can be overrided. Having in mind that every instance of (created from single) mesh can have its own position, rotation, scale and even color I though that also UV map modified so it is specific to each instance because in fact it is quite logical.

(2/2) It is a pity it does not work like this. Correct me if I am wrong but in order to apply separate UV maps to different instances I have to convert them first into mesh. However - I am asking because I am quite a beginner with Blender - can I convert the instances into separate meshes so each instance is a seperate mesh and do it all in geometry nodes or conversion of instances into mesh creates one big mesh.

@JanPips The thing with each mesh having its own position is that it's not the mesh vertices having their own positions, only the base location of each instance has its own position. The vertices inside the instances all have the exact same data, the relative offset from their base location. And as Markus said, since UV maps are mesh data, they are all the same across the instances.
